# Why doesn't CSS text-align:left work with Simplebar?

Tags: html, css, text-align, simplebar

I've encountered a problem with text-align:left: my messages(text) don't align to the left. I've tried several things so far: adding width:100%, float:left and also display:block. Unfortunately, none of them worked. I was thinking that probably simplebar affects it though I can't figure out how then. Would be so grateful if you could help me somehow! 
Here is my CSS and HTML:

```
<h2 id="receiver" name="{{receiver}}">Chat with {{receiver}}</h2>
    <div data-simplebar id="my-element" class="history">
      {% for message in hist_list %}
        {{message}}<br>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

.history {
  position: absolute;
  top: 210px;
  left: 249px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 416px;
  text-align:left;
  width:100%;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}
```

This is Simpebar which might interfere with my CSS:

```
[data-simplebar] {
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should remove `text-align:center;` from universal selecter. Hope below snippet helps.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
/*   text-align: center; */
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}
#receiver{
  text-align:center;
}

.history {
  position: absolute;
  height: 416px;
  text-align:left;
  width:100%;
}


[data-simplebar] {
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="receiver" name="">Chat with Name</h2>
<div data-simplebar id="my-element" class="history">
  <p>This is a message</p><br>
  <p>This is a message</p><br>
</div>
```

Comment: this one works! thank you a lot! it was actually pretty straightforward... shame on me for not coming up with it on my own!

Comment: Everyone makes mistakes :)  Im glad that my answer helped. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

SO there is a small thing you can do to fix your problem, just call your universal selector code above all the things,

just like this,

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}
.history {
  position: absolute;
  top: 210px;
  left: 249px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 416px;
  text-align:left;
  width:100%;
}
```

CSS is cascading and it gives prefrence to the code which is written after, just see this small example

```css
p {color: red; font-size: 100px;}
p {color: green; font-size: 50px;}
```

```html
<p>Test</p>
```

So in the given example, code which is written below, I.e the color green's one, will get the preference, So its good practice to write the universal selector at top of your code and then use all the other thing which you want to over write below it.

Comment: I disagree with the claim that "there is only one thing you can do" - although it probably is the cleanest and most simple fix.

Comment: @SwimmerF agree with you, Actually I didn't mean that, Changed the line which I actually meant.

Comment: My universal selector is actually written at the top of my code but here I put it below, sorry. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

just remove transform and absolute

```css
.history {
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* top: 210px; */
    /* left: 249px; */
    /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
    height: 416px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```